# Property-based testing for a chess game

Tags: haskell, testing, chess

I'm trying to wrap my mind around property-based testing and chess. Currently I represent my chess game as a 2d-array and the only pieces I have implemented are pawns and knights for grokking this.

The pawn and knight represent their moves as the set of `allMoves(x,y) \ invalidMoves(board,x,y)`. So one property I can think of is to test that `allMoves(x,y) ∪ invalidMoves(board,x,y) === allMoves`. But beyond that I'm not sure what else to test. I assume that I need to set up a simplified oracle model for the chess board but I'm not sure what such a model would be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by just saying some obvious things that are true about real-life chess boards, no matter how dumb they sound. Many of those will be reasonable properties to test. Here are some ideas:

- When you move a piece, it moves from the place where it was to the place where the move puts it.
- No legal knight move is ever a legal pawn move.
- A pawn never moves more than two squares at once.
- A knight never moves adjacent to its starting position.
- A move should only involve positions actually on the board.
- Moving onto another piece decreases the number of pieces on the board.

Many more ideas like this exist. They seem simple, but I guarantee your early implementations will miss some of them. Figure out how to write these invariants as properties, and grow your test suite from there.

Comment: Those last two look really good. The first one also has potential. The rest look a bit specific to me; I'd only stick those in a test suite as regression tests after I fixed a bug.

Comment: Ok, but for doing this would I not need to simulate an entire board, basically reimplementing the program twice? Usually we want the model to be some simpler version that is different from the original implementation right? For example a queue can be tested using only an int checking it's size, so we would want someting similar here? 

" move should only involve positions actually on the board. " This one would be possible to test knowing only the bounds of the board so that should be possible.

Comment: Just use your real board. Why do you think you need a fake, model board? Test that, for any board, for any move that board offers, that move satisfies your properties.

Comment: @dfeuer Reasonable. I was brainstorming here, writing down anything I thought of regardless of how useful it sounds, to emphasize that this is a useful process for deriving properties. (A better version of the knight property is that a knight's move always takes it to a different-color square)